# Срабатывание события при наведение на бордюр окружности

Tags: javascript, css, css3, svg, анимация

Имеется зеленая окружность. Каким  образом повесить событие так, чтобы оно срабатывало  при наведение на окружность (я её зелёным выделил)?

Если курсор находится за пределами окружности или внутри, то событие не должно срабатывать.

Как я понял, такое можно реализовать только с костылями? Если да, то конкретно в какую сторону копать?

Вообще, мне подобный функционал нужен при наведение на окружности нарисованную в SVG, но думаю, суть в любом случае одна. Буду рад за всякую помощь.

P.S. добавил пример окружности с SVG тоже [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/p07gmt4L/1/)

```html
<div style="border: solid 10px green; border-radius: 50%; width: 200px; height: 200px;">

</div>

<svg style="transform: rotate(-180deg);" width="200" height="200" viewPort="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle r="95" cx="100" cy="100" fill="transparent" stroke="#05afd3" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="596.9026041820607" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Если вам нужно для `svg`, то добавьте пример `svg`.

Comment: что нужно сделать ?

Comment: @НикитаФаст получается нужен Hover на Border

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Если курсор находится за пределами окружности или внутри, то событие
>   не должно срабатывать.

Чтобы событие,- *изменение цвета бордюра окружности*, не срабатывало при нахождении курсора внутри окружности, необходимо задать `fill:none;`
При задании, как у вас `fill="transparent"` окружность заполнена прозрачным цветом. Она не пустая, поэтому при наведении курсора событие будет срабатывать.

Остается, как правильно заметили в комментарии,- добавить в CSS `:hover` для бордюра (строки) окружности.

```
#crc1:hover {
stroke:#05afd3;
}
```

Ниже полный код

```css
#crc1 {
stroke:green;
stroke-width:10;
fill:none;

}
#crc1:hover {
stroke:#05afd3;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200"  >  

<circle id="crc1" r="95" cx="100" cy="100"/> 
</svg>
```

**Вариант с анимацией изменения цвета бордюра окружности**

```css
#crc1 {
stroke:#05afd3;
stroke-width:10;
fill:none; 
 transition: all 0.8s ease-out;

}
#crc1:hover {
stroke:red;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200"  >  

<circle id="crc1" r="95" cx="100" cy="100"/> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я ещё тогда разобрался, вот только руки не дошли сюда решение скинуть. И да, спасибо большое, в любом случае!

Answer (score 3):

В контур круга разорван для того что бы убедится что событие срабатывает только на самом контуре ...
Это можно проверить если провести курсором внутри

```html
<svg version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 410 497" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path id="ellipse"d="m37.042 38.464c9.9289-8.8032 19.858-17.607 31.673-23.25 11.815-5.6436 25.517-8.1278 38.831-6.9596 13.314 1.1682 26.242 5.9885 36.843 13.403 10.602 7.414 18.878 17.422 24.314 28.448s8.0336 23.071 7.7991 34.726c-0.2345 11.655-3.3007 22.922-8.1285 32.949-4.8278 10.027-11.417 18.814-20.555 25.793s-20.823 12.151-33.016 14.464c-12.193 2.313-24.893 1.7676-35.785-0.7682-10.892-2.5358-19.977-7.0622-28.405-14.427-8.4282-7.3647-16.2-17.568-20.746-29.389s-5.8679-25.262-7.1893-38.702" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="6"/>
</svg>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#ellipse").on("mouseover", function() {
    alert("its ellipse");
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за идею. Многие ребята здесь помогли и вы в том числе. Теперь мне есть над чем подумать. Кстати, а нельзя тоже самое провернуть с `cirсle`, а не `path`?

Comment: path тоже замкнутый контур - именно line нужен - его можно не замыкать , в случае с path как вы  попадёте внутрь что бы проверить есть ли event внутри ?